# Read html text from variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS variable that holds html code for embedding a YouTube video,
which looks like:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/....." 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there any way to simply read the html from the variable? Or must I extract the URL from the variable and surround it with the iframe tag framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about reading the HTML code **inside** the `iframe`, then you **can't** do that with JavaScript: take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/)** for more information.

If you want to add the frame on your document you can do it using the `innerHTML` property of an element, for example:

```
var myFrame = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/....." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

document.getElementById("container-id").innerHTML += myFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML have following tag you need to add "id" as a attribute.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/....." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="iframe1"></iframe>
```

You can read properties in this way:

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').getAttribute('frameborder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code

```
<body>
<div id="DIV">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
   var content = document.getElementById('DIV');
   var frame = "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/.....'
frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
   content.innerHTML = frame ;   
</script>
</body>
```